# New Way to View Reputation Changes

Tags: feature-request, reputation

When I view my user profile, I can easily get a list of all the most recent activity associated with my account. However, if I see a change to my reputation, it's much harder for me to determine what caused the change.

I've found the Reputation tab, but that doesn't seem ideal (and, in fact, seems a little awkward for tracking very recent changes).

What would be great is if the Activity tab included a reputation section similar to the other activity sections. So it would show I got 10 rep points for this comment, etc. starting with the most recent.

As it is, I find I'm having trouble tracking a number of changes to my reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the envelope next to your name at the top of any page.  You can then click the reputation tab and select the interval you want to view.

For instance, here's the reputation you've earned today on SO:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/522663?Tab=Reputation&StartDate=2011-01-23&EndDate=2011-01-23

Comment: The mailbox icon has recently disappeared!  What happened to it?

Answer (score 1):

The /recent is where you want to go.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/522663?startdate=2011-01-23%2022:24:38z&enddate=2011-01-23%2023:59:59z&tab=reputation#tab-top

I got this link by subbing your ID for mine.  I believe it only works for the person owning the ID.

Another option is https://stackoverflow.com/reputation (audit), but that gets progressively longer and you need something like a GreaseMonkey script to bring in the questions the changes relate to, but please do it on hover or some such and not the entire page (it will be a massive hit on SO)